# TypeError: __webpack_require__(...) is not a function

Tags: webpack

When doing a webpack build or running a website with webpack I get random errors about require not being a function. This happens on different modules at different points on a deeply nested callstack of require resolutions.

I have googled this error extensively and found it can be caused by lots of different symptoms. I have tried all of them that I can find and none of them worked for me.

I'm posting this with a solution to show what worked for me in case somebody else might have the same issue.

Here is the relevant part of the webpack set:

```
/**
 * @returns {import('webpack').RuleSetRule}
 */
module.exports = () => ({
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(query-string|strict-uri-encode|modernizr|split-on-first)\/).*/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: [
        [ '@babel/preset-env', {
          // - If useBuiltIns: 'usage' is specified in .babelrc then do not include @babel/polyfill in either webpack.config.js entry array
          //   nor source. Note, @babel/polyfill still needs to be installed.
          // - If useBuiltIns: 'entry' is specified in .babelrc then include @babel/polyfill at the top of the entry point to your application
          //   via require or import
          // - If useBuiltIns key is not specified or it is explicitly set with useBuiltIns: false in your .babelrc, add @babel/polyfill
          //   directly to the entry array in your webpack.config.js.
          useBuiltIns: 'usage',
          corejs: '2'
        } ]
      ],
      plugins: [
        ['@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs', {
          strictMode: false
        }]
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

The above loader for babel gives the following errors:

```
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
    TypeError: __webpack_require__(...) is not a function
        at Object.I8a+ (C:\TRAVLR\Repos\Travlr\Webs\WebApp\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!C:\TRAVLR\Repos\Travlr\Webs\WebApp\node_modules\postcss-loader\src\index.js??ref--6-2!C:\TRAVLR\Repos\Travlr\Webs\WebApp\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!C:\TRAVLR\Repos\Travlr\Library\UiKit\src\scss\app.scss:580:38)
```

OR

````
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/core-js/modules/_classof.js?:4)
    at Object../node_modules/core-js/modules/_classof.js (pkg.core-js.js:889)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.client.js:782)
    at fn (runtime.client.js:150)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.object.to-string.js?:3)
    at Object../node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.object.to-string.js (pkg.core-js.js:2167)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.client.js:782)
    at fn (runtime.client.js:150)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.regexp.to-string.js?:11)
    at Object../node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.regexp.to-string.js (pkg.core-js.js:2306)```
````

Answer (score 0):

The thing that worked for me was to change the following line from the above file:
`useBuiltIns: 'usage'`
to
`useBuiltIns: 'entry'`

Note that this may not work for you. This same error seems to have many different causes.